# Resumable Upload in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, resume-upload

I am looking for a resumable-file-upload component to use in my RoR app. I found one: http://github.com/taf2/resume-up/tree/master (built in native Ruby, but it requires google gears which is a discontinued product now..)

Also, http://github.com/dassi/mediaclue is another app in which they have used jumploader java applet. more on it: jumploader.come

Is there a way to achieve this functionality without using java-applet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://upload.thinfile.com/upload/thin.php - its quite cheap and you can try the demo for free. You'll need to build a controller.

Comment: This worked out great. I was able to develop the RoR controller code for it with ease. I hope they make file upload resume as HTML5 standard.